# Blogs similar to Err The Blog

Tags: ruby, blogs

What's a dev blog that continues the innovative quality of PJ Hyett's and Chris Wanstrath's discontinued Err The Blog?  Ruby or otherwise.

http://errtheblog.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of some Ruby blogs that I enjoy. I'm not sure that any of them can match the link you posted above.

- [QuirkeyBlog](http://www.quirkey.com/blog/)
- [techno weenie](http://techno-weenie.net/)
- [afreshcup (mostly covers Ruby on Rails)](http://afreshcup.com/)
- [Giant Robots](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/)